# Series simplification (u1+1000)*1,1 = U2

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I simplify a series like this one in order to have an function to easily calculate $u_x$ ?

$$(u_0+1000) \times 1,1 = u_1  $$
$$(u_1+1000)\times1,1 = u_2  $$
$$(u_2+1000)\times1,1 = u_3$$

Moreover what kind of series it is ?

I looked for a geometric series and arithmetico-geometric series but it doesn't seem that are the one I'm looking for.

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write mathematical expressions.

Comment: It looks like an arithmetico-geometric series to me, isn't it ?